# React Hooks - Prevent deep comparison causing infinite rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a react hook as follows.

I wait for the user object to be loaded via the useSelector react-redux hook, and then update the firebase query used by th `useFirestoreConnect` hook.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState({
    collection: 'account',
    query: [['userId', '==', user.uid]]
  })

  const user = useSelector(state => state.firebase.profile)

  useFirestoreConnect(query)

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = user.uid ? user.uid ? null
    setQuery({
      collection: 'account',
      query: [['userId', '==', null]]
    })
  }, [user, initialQuery])
}
```

Since the object passed to `useFirestoreConnect` is new every time, it forces a re-render indefinitely. To make this work, I've had to write some ugly code to make sure that I am just updating the state with a mutated version of an object. This is horrible. Since my re-render is only conditional on user.uid, is there a way to "wrap" the `useFirestoreConnect` such that I would only be passing in a singular string for simple comparison?

Thanks for any insight or am I approaching this wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to use `useMemo` to force a return of the same object for the same input parameters.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

  const user = useSelector(state => state.firebase.profile)

  const query = useMemo(
    () => ({
      collection: 'account',
      where: [['userId', '==', user.uid ? user.uid : null]],
    }),
    [user]
  )
  useFirestoreConnect(query)
}
```